# Reindex columns after using crosstab with regular month order instead of alphabetic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I have the following output after use crosstab, see image attached:

[image]

My question is the following: How can I sort the columns by month based on year position instead of by alphabetical order?

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['col1'], df['col2']).reindex(['Jan','Feb',...], axis=1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from calendar import month_abbr

df.reindex(columns=month_abbr[1:])
```

In the built-in [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module, there is [`month_abbr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_abbr) that gives abbreviation of the months. Its length, however, is 13 as it includes an empty string at index 0 (to ease the regular indexing like 3 is for March etc.). In short, you can use it to re-index your data frame over `columns`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with `pandas` just create a yearly date_range with month frequency then `strftime` to get the abbreviations.

```
import pandas as pd

cols = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31', freq='MS').strftime('%b')
#Index(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
#       'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']),

df = df.reindex(cols, axis=1)
```